# MVC3 sending hashed password with ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating a loginform like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnComplete = "onComplete"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, "Username")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, "Wachtwoord")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remember, "Remember me")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remember)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remember)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Inloggen" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Now the password is send unhashed over the internet for validation to the model, which is not safe. I want to make sure the password is always hashed going over the line and preventing man in the middle sniffers.

The onBegin won't work because the elements cannot be modified anymore after this, any other ideas?

Comment: shouldn't you be using https?

Comment: This is the function that HTTPS serves. Why not use it?

Comment: As MedicineMan says, you should be using https, specially on your login page.

Comment: fair enough I am considering this (as https certificates are as cheap as 12 euro), but still this is not possible then in MVC (for future reference).

Comment: Why do you think hashing a password in your browser is "safer?" If I'm a man in the middle and can see a password, then I can see a hashed password, too. If your site will accept that, then I can still make a man in the middle attack work. As others have said, use HTTPS.

Comment: that is true, but with a safe hash it will be more difficult to actually see which password the user has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without ajax by catching the submit event and hash the password before posting the form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn","Login",FormMethod.Post,new {id = "loginForm"})) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {id = "password"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Connect"  id="submit"/>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>}
```

For example with this javascript code :

```
      $(function () {
          $("#loginForm").on("submit",function (e) {

              var form = $(this);
              var pass = $("#password").val();
              $("#password").val(MD5(token + MD5(pass)));

              form.submit();
          });

      });
```

Comment: in fact, it misses : e.preventDefault()